# Function not in $C^\infty(\overline{\mathbb{\Omega}})\cap W^{1,p}$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

$\Omega=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}: 0<|x|<1,0<y<1\}$. $u:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by:
\begin{align}
u(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1, & \mbox{x > 0} \\ 0, & \mbox{x < 0} \end{cases}
\end{align}

$u$ cannot be approximated by any squence of functions in  $C^\infty(\overline{\mathbb{\Omega}})\cap W^{1,p}$.

---

My approach:

$u$ is in $L^1(\Omega)$ and $u$ is $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$, because the region on which $u$ is non differentiable$(x=0)$ is not in the domain. $\therefore$ $u$ is in $W^{1,p}$ and in $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$. From here how do I show the above?

P.S. Do I show that there exists no sequence of functions in $C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ that tends to $u$?

Comment: When you say "approximated by", what topology do you mean?  The same in your last sentence when you say "tends to".

Comment: In the last reference ie the "tends to" one, I think it should be the $L^1$ norm.